# What is the use of '??' operator

Tags: dart

While reading some code in Dart I came across this line of code:

```
dead = parsedJson['dead'] ?? false,
```

What does the `??` operator do in Dart?  How is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a replacement for `is null`.

So, in your example, if `parsedJson['dead']` is null, then `dead` value will be assigned `false`. Otherwise, it will be assigned whatever `parsedJson['dead']` current value is.

Answer (score 4):

`??` is the *if null operator*. It can be used when you want to evaluate and return an expression if and only if another expression resolves to `null`.

```
exp ?? otherExp
```

is similar to

```
((x) => x == null ? otherExp : x)(exp)
```

In your case, `dead` will get the value of `parsedJson['dead']` and if it is `null` it will be `false`